# Setting default direction to RTL

Tags: tinymce, right-to-left

I install Tinymce editor to my site. And now i need to set the default direction to RTL not LTR.You can see below--

```js
 tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea#editor',
        directionality :"rtl"
});
```

I want to set  this

[image: result]

How can i do that ??

Answer (score 9):

If you are going to use it for Arabic language [Download](http://jquery-php-css3-html-mysql.blogspot.com/2013/05/40b3-tinymce-filemanager.html) the Arabic version

or use this code to set default direction rtl

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea#editor",  
  plugins: "directionality",
  directionality :"rtl",
  toolbar: "ltr rtl"
});
```

and for the orientation of the toolbar options try to contact TinyMCE.

I hope this may help you.

Comment: I did it like that:
```tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea', 
  rtl_ui:true 
});```